# Growing this series

Tags: number-theory

Recently I finished a Project euler the sum of multiples of five ant three I get this results:

```
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 10 collect i)))
33
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 100 collect i)))
2418
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 1000 collect i)))
234168
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 10000 collect i)))
23341668
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 100000 collect i)))
2333416668
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 1000000 collect i)))
233334166668
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 10000000 collect i)))
23333341666668
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (or (= 0 (mod x 3)) (= 0 (mod x 5)))) (loop for i from 0 to 100000000 collect i)))
2333333416666668
```

I test with adding zeros to the request, and I get something that is similar to a ppattern 2(threes)41(sixes)8, of the number, it is always true, and how I will get this answer, what I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the desired number be $f(n)$.
The sum of all naturals up to $n$ is well-known:
$$\tag1\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
The sum of all multiples of $c$ up to $cn$ is accordingly $ \frac{cn(n+1)}{2} $. Thus the sum of all multiples of $c$ up to $n$ (which may fail to be a multiple of $c$) is
$$\tag2g(n,c):=\sum_{1\le k\le n\atop c\mid k} k =\frac{c\lfloor n/c\rfloor (\lfloor n/c\rfloor+1)}{2}.$$
Now for the problem at hand, we start add $(2)$ for $c=3$ and for $c=5$ to get all multiples of $3$ or $5$. However, that would count all multiples of $15$ twice, so we need to subtract them. Thus the final result is
$$\begin{align}f(n)&=g(n,3)+g(n,5)-g(n,15)\\& = \frac{3\lfloor n/3\rfloor(\lfloor n/3\rfloor+1)+ 5\lfloor n/5\rfloor(\lfloor n/5\rfloor+1)-15\lfloor n/15\rfloor(\lfloor n/15\rfloor+1)}{2}\end{align} $$

Not only does this give you an $O(1)$ solution to the problem, but we may indeed use that to verify patterns like the one you describe.
In fact, your pattern boils down to the

**Claim.** Let $m\in\Bbb N$ and $n=10^m$. Then 
$$f(n)= \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{2(n^2-1)}9}_{22\ldots\ldots2}+ \underbrace{\frac{n^2-10}{90}}_{1\ldots\ldots1}+\underbrace{\frac{n-1}3}_{33\ldots3}+\underbrace{\frac n2}_{50\ldots0}+2}_{23\ldots3416\ldots 68}=\frac{7n^2+25n+40}{30}$$

As a matter of fact, we have the more general

**Claim.** Let $n\in\Bbb N$ with $n\equiv 10\pmod{15}$. Then 
$$f(n)= \frac{7n^2+25n+40}{30}$$

Can you show this claim? The key is that knowing $n\bmod 15$ allows you to express $\lfloor n/3\rfloor$ etc. nicely.